# Mobile First 8 application does not reconnect after time in background

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Technologies:

- IBM Mobile First 8
- Ionic v1.x

**Problem description:**
I use the application... then, I put it in background some time, but when I try to use it after that time passes, the application cannot connect to MFP server; therefore, I have to close the app to use it again.
I tried to solve this issue putting the next line on the onResume event: WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(), but it does not work.
Thanks!

Comment: When you bring it back from background and then try to connect to MFP server, what do you see in the device logs? And is this common to iOS and Android or only one of the platforms?

Comment: It happens in both. I cannot see any kind of error in the devices logs. And the application does not receive response from the server.

Comment: @HernánGiraldo You mean you will receive "Request Timeout" error in the call back of obtainAccessToken API ? What is your cordova mfp plugin version ?

Comment: Sorry!!! After hours and hours of debugging my code, I could find the error... It was my mistake. I had a property in my code that blocks all server responses. Thanks for your attention and your answers.

Comment: @HernánGiraldo, Can you please write what was wrong as an answer. So that anyone possibly encountering similar issue can find it helpful?